# Data from ES6 promise doesn't render on the page until I click on it?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angular-promise, es6-promise

I an using Ionic for my app with a connection to Firebase to pull data. I created a promise in a factory to pull data down and thought it should render the data on the screen once it finishes but I'm getting nothing until I touch the screen?

I get no error and the data does indeed come.

Factory:

```
all: function () {
          return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase.database().ref('desks').once('value').then(snapshot => {
              let desks = [] 
              snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                desks.push(child.val());
              });
              resolve(desks)
            });
          });

}
```

Calling the Factory:

```
Office.all().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.officeList = data;
});
```

I feel I'm calling it wrong or else there is an Ionic method that I can't seem to find.

How will I be able to have the data render once it finishes the request?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Discussed so many times. Promise callbacks are executed out of Angular's scope, so *dirty checking* does not work and bindings do not update. Just use `$scope.$apply();` after assigning data `$scope.officeList = data;`

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go. Not sure why I didn't come across it when looking for it :/. Hoping to move the react native some time so hopefully it'll be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 promises are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Use [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) to convert ES6 promises to AngularJS promises. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

```
all: function () {

      ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶P̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶ ̶(̶(̶r̶e̶s̶o̶l̶v̶e̶,̶ ̶r̶e̶j̶e̶c̶t̶)̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶{̶        
    var es6promise = firebase.database()
      .ref('desks').once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
          let desks = [] 
          snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            desks.push(child.val());
          });
          ̶r̶e̶s̶o̶l̶v̶e̶(̶d̶e̶s̶k̶s̶)̶
          return desks;
    });

    return $q.when(es6promise);
}
```

Also avoid using `Promise(resolve,reject` to create new promises. Instead use the promise returned by the  [.then method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api). It returns a *new promise* which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues)).

For more information, see [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).